# Get params sent to a subcommand of a click.group()

Tags: python, python-click

If I have a `click.group()` with multiple sub-commands, is there a way that I can get the command line arguments passed to those sub-commands within the group itself?

I know you can go from the group downwards via the `context`, and I know that I can use a `callback` function that will execute before the command, but I didn't know if there was a better way to do this than use a `callback`.

An example:

```
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument('task')
@click.argument('task_id')
def sync(task, task_id):
    click.echo('Synching: {}'.format(task))
```

In this example, is there any way to get `task` or `task_id` in the group method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done by over riding the `click.Group.invoke()` method like:

**Custom Class:**

```
class MyGroup(click.Group):
    def invoke(self, ctx):
        ctx.obj = tuple(ctx.args)
        super(MyGroup, self).invoke(ctx)
```

**Using Custom Class:**

Then to use the custom group, pass it as the `cls` argument to the `group` decorator like:

```
@click.group(cls=MyGroup)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    args = ctx.obj
    ....
```

**How does this work?**

This works because `click` is a well designed OO framework.  The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter.  So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Group.invoke()` and grab the arguments and put them into the `ctx.obj` field. They are then accessible in the `cli()` function.

**Test Code:**

```
import click

class MyGroup(click.Group):
    def invoke(self, ctx):
        ctx.obj = tuple(ctx.args)
        super(MyGroup, self).invoke(ctx)

@click.group(cls=MyGroup)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    args = ctx.obj
    click.echo('cli: {} {}'.format(ctx.invoked_subcommand, ' '.join(args)))

@cli.command()
@click.argument('task')
@click.argument('task_id')
def sync(task, task_id):
    click.echo('Synching: {}'.format(task))

cli('sync task taskid'.split())
```

**Results:**

```
cli: sync task taskid
Synching: task
```

Comment: Brilliant! This does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!